# Internet Explorer - ReactJS doesn't lost data after refresh (F5)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I got an issue as bellow:
I have a ReactJS web page as tutorial I refer [here](https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-react-registration-login-example), when I run on IE, after enter data to input text and press F5, my page continue display data even though the value is updated to nothing. So how to remove all data? please help.

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: I refer this tutorial [link](https://github.com/cornflourblue/aspnet-core-react-registration-login-example), login page with inputs tag like below :
`code <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" value={username} onChange={this.handleChange} />`

Comment: You can edit your question to add more detail.